# Logarithmic or exponential fitting of a function given two points

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Let $BPM$ stand for *beats per minute*. Another quantity $x$ is to be calculated from the value of BPM on a logarithmic or exponential scale.

For $BPM = 120$, $x$ should be $0.01$.

For $BPM = 80$, $x$ should be $0.004$.

What is the way to plug this into some formula?

Comment: logarithmic **or** exponential scale? The answer will very much depend on which one you want. You could start with the desired form for the equation. Perhaps you'll want something like
$$
x = a\cdot \log (BPM) +b
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants. But you can create something else too. So what kind of form do you want? Alternatively, you could roughly sketch (draw) the graph of the function that you would like to have. Also: what is the application? I assume BPM is short for Beats Per Minute, so what are you trying to calculate here?

Comment: I guess exponentially but with a "damping" factor. So as the bpm increases, x gets larger i.e at bpm = 80 x is 0.004 but as the bpm increases through 80 to 120, x increases from 0.004 to 0.01.
Basically I am translating the BPM of the song into a value that dictates the speed change of the y axis of a wave function

Comment: I understood these values. You want $f(80) = 0.004$ and $f(120)=0.010$. That's clear. But what do you mean with a "damping factor"? Do you mean that you want the curve to "flatten out" as the input value (BPM) gets larger?

Comment: Yes, sorry I would like the increase from 80-120 to be bigger than say 120-150, which is why I initially thought it would be a logrithmic scale

Comment: Wait, this is to do with a song's beats per minute & amplitude speed change? Well, in that case I'm sure there's already a physical model relating them.

Comment: To be fair there probably is, im just having a crack my self using the perlin noise algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the requirements are rather vague, but I'll just provide a straight-up answer. I'll interpret that the wish is to have a function of the form
$$
x = f(BPM) =  a\cdot \ln (BPM) +b
$$
We know the two conditions, $f(80) = 0.004$ and $f(120)=0.010$. Plugging these in, we get (a bit scary-looking) expressions for $a$ and $b$:
$$
a = \frac{0.06}{\ln \frac{3}{2}} \approx 0.014~798
$$
$$
b = \frac{  \frac{\ln 80}{ \ln 120}\cdot 0.010 - 0.004   }{\frac{\ln 80}{ \ln 120} - 1 } \approx -0.060~844
$$
So the function that you wanted is, as I interpret it,
$$
x = (0.014~798) \cdot \ln BPM -(0.060~844)
$$
Are you happy with this?

Comment: Yes, this works. Apologies for being vague, need to work on being more concise. Thank you very much

Comment: The question gives two points and asks for logarithmic or exponential. The exponential solution is 
$$x=\frac{2}{3125}\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^\frac{BPM}{40}$$